# WP Gravity forms w/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm aiming write a Javascript code that would take a data from a Gravity Forms dropdown menu (the data will be either +1, +2, or +3 - which serves to select the number of days the customers would like to extend their holidays), and apply this number to a date selector in Gravity Forms.
The problem is that I'm not sure how to grab the data from those specific fields of Gravity Forms.

Could you please suggest any solutions?

Comment: Two solutions that might get you close. The first is for populating a modified date into a date field based on user interaction. The second allows you to limit the datepicker options that are available.

1. http://gravitywiz.com/populate-dates-gravity-form-fields/
2. http://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-limit-dates/

Comment: @David thank you for the input. However, I would like to use jQuery to automatically populate a date field - the user would select a certain date; then from the other field they would select the number of days for extension; and then the jquery would automatically populate another field with the final date (original date + the number of days selected for extension). Would you know how can this be achieved?

Comment: Hi Marian, feel free to post a comment on the first article which will get you most of the way there on this in regards to populating the date. You'll need to handle modifying the date by the selected value from the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

You might have gotten this already, but I've been messing with the following to good results.  I'm using it to edit a list field, but it might get you started in the right direction.  I'm new to jQuery so it isn't perfect...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// START Place Jquery in here
//$() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
$( "select" ).change(function() {
  var str = "";
$( "{INPUT CLASS}:selected" ).each(function() {
  str += $( this ).val() + "1";
});
$( "{OUTPUT CLASS} input" ).val( str );
})
.trigger( "change" );
// END
});
```